# How to write the following equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

I need this output with the same harpoon right arrow:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\vect{L^2((0,T);W^{1,2}(\Omega)')}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use an extensible harpoon that is has a width proportionate to the other content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx,accents}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\accentset{\xrightharpoonup{\hphantom{\scalebox{.4}{$#1$}}}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \vect{L^2((0,T);W^{1,2}(\Omega)')}
\]
\end{document}
```

The content is scaled to 40% of its width (change `.4` to suit your needs) and only uses the `h`orizontal width in a `\phantom`. The extensible harpoon is provided as part of [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (which loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) by default).